# Unable to parse the snapshot of Firebase with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an query and it returns snapshot;

```
ref.orderByChild("index").equalTo(currentIndex).once("value", function(snapshot) {})
```

When I print snapshot with ;

```
console.log(snapshot.val());
```

it is printed as follows;

```
{'-LBHEpgffPTQnxWIT4DI':
    {
        date: '16.05.2018',
        first: 'let me in',
        index: 1,
        second: 'let others in'
    }
},
```

I need to take the value date, first value of this snapshot.

I tried;

```
childSnapshot.val()["first"] 
childSnapshot.val()["date"]
```

or

```
childSnapshot.child.('first') 
childSnapshot.child.('date')
```

but there is no success.

Please indicate me the mistake I am doing...

My full code is as below;

```
var indexRef = db.ref("/LastIndex/");
var ref = db.ref("/Source/")

indexRef.on("value", function(indexSnapshot) {
    console.log(indexSnapshot.val());

    var currentIndex = indexSnapshot.val()

    ref.orderByChild("index").equalTo(currentIndex).once("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());

        if(snapshot !== null) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            if(childSnapshot !== null) {
                var newRef = db.ref("/ListTest/");
                var key = newRef.push({
                    "firstLanguageWord": childSnapshot.val()["first"] ,
                    "secondLanguageWord": childSnapshot.val()["second"] ,
                    "wordType": childSnapshot.val()["type"],
                    "date": childSnapshot.val()["date"],
                    "translateType": childSnapshot.val()["transType"]
                });

                currentIndex++;
                indexRef.set(currentIndex);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

BR,

Erdem

Answer (score 1):

**Update, following your comments below and the update to the original question:**

If it appears that your code is "iterating infinitely" it is because you use the on() method with your first query. As a matter of facts, the `on()` method "listens for data changes at a particular location.", as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on).

If you just want to query once the reference, use the `once()` method instead. The doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once).

---

The following is a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), because you call the `orderByChild()` method on a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) (as well as an `equalTo()` method).

```
ref.orderByChild("index").equalTo(currentIndex)
```

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) in the doc:

> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is
>   still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you
>   need to loop over the result:
>
> ```
> ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {  
>   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>     // ...   
>    }); 
> });
> ```

So you should do:

```
ref.orderByChild("index").equalTo(currentIndex).once("value", function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        console.log(childSnapshot.val().first);
        console.log(childSnapshot.val().date);      
       }); 
});
```

Comment: I have also tried that @Renaud Tarnec. Howewer, this time it keeps iterating infinitely.

Comment: @erdemgc Strange... can you share your full code and not only the part on the query.once()?

Comment: @erdemgc Ok I understand: it is normal it kind of "iterate infinitely": you use the `on()` method, which "Listens for data changes at a particular location.". Can you explain in more detail what is your business need. What do you try to achieve? I see you are combining two references but you should chain the two asynchronous functions. If you give more details  on your goal (by adapting your question) I should be able to help you.

Comment: I want to take data from one node to another node, the data is here is an object

Comment: With the light you have burnt, changing "on" for indexRef to "once" solved the problem. Thanks @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: @erdemgc I've updated my answer to reflect the different comments we exchanged above. If you consider that my answer brought you some value, you may upvote it. Thanks.